# Get filtered row count using dm_db_partition_stats

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using paging in my app but I've noticed that paging has gone very slow and the line below is the culprit:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM MyTable
```

On my table, which only has 9 million rows, it takes 43 seconds to return the row count. I read in another article which states that to return the row count for 1.4 billion rows, it takes over 5 minutes. This obviously cannot be used with paging as it is far too slow and the only reason I need the row count is to calculate the number of available pages.

After a bit of research I found out that I get the row count pretty much instantly (and accurately) using the following:

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1)
```

But the above returns me the count for the entire table which is fine if no filters are applied but how do I handle this if I need to apply filters such as a date range and/or a status?

For example, what is the row count for MyTable when the DateTime field is between 2013-04-05 and 2013-04-06 and status='warning'?

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1**

In case I wasn't clear, I require the total number of rows available so that I can determine the number of pages required that will match my query when using 'paging' feature. For example, if a page returns 20 records and my total number of records matching my query is 235, I know I'll need to display 12 buttons below my grid.

01 - (row 1 to 20) - 20 rows displayed in grid.
02 - (row 21 to 40) - 20 rows displayed in grid.
...
11 - (row 200 to 220) - 20 rows displayed in grid.
12 - (row 221 to 235) - 15 rows displayed in grid.

There will be additional logic added to handle a large amount of pages but that's a UI issue, so this is out of scope for this topic.

My problem with using "Select count(*) from MyTable" is that it is taking 40+ seconds on 9 million records (thought it isn't anymore and I need to find out why!) but using this method I was able to add the same filter as my query to determine the query. For example,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN '2018-04-05' AND '2018-04-06' AND
      [Status] = 'Warning'
```

Once I determine the page count, I would then run the same query but include the fields instead of count(*), the CurrentPageNo and PageSize in order to filter my results by page number using the row ids and navigate to a specific pages if needed.

```
SELECT RowId, DateTime, Status, Message FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [DateTime] BETWEEN '2018-04-05' AND '2018-04-06' AND
      [Status] = 'Warning' AND
      RowId BETWEEN (CurrentPageNo * PageSize) AND ((CurrentPageNo + 1) * PageSize)
```

Now, if I use the other mentioned method to get the row count i.e.

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1)
```

It returns the count instantly but how do I filter this so that I can include the same filters as if I was using the `SELECT COUNT(*)` method, so I could end up with something like:

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('MyTable') AND 
(index_id=0 or index_id=1) AND
([DateTime] BETWEEN '2018-04-05' AND '2018-04-06') AND
([Status] = 'Warning')
```

The above clearing won't work as I'm querying the dm_db_partition_stats but I would like to know if I can somehow perform a join or something similar to provide me with the total number of rows instantly but it needs to be filtered rather than apply to the entire table.

Thanks.

Comment: Your fastest result is probably to do a COUNT(*) query and index the columns in the filter.   Either that or build (and maintain ) a pre-aggregated table(s).

Comment: @TabAlleman Odd, after reading your reply, I was about to reply that my table already had a primary key which I thought would have sufficed but when I ran a basic select count(*), I noticed that instead of taking 43 secs, it took 1 sec and I went hmmm??? The only thing I did was to add an index on my DateTime field which isn't being used as I'm not filtering by DateTime just yet so I'm baffled as to why this is now executing so much faster. Still slower than I'd like it to be and would rather an instant result but this is already far better. I will research this further and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever asked for directions to alpha centauri? No? Well the answer is, you can't get there from here.

Adding indexes, re-orgs/re-builds, updating stats will only get you so far. You should consider changing your approach.

sp_spaceused will return the record count typically instantly; You may be able to use this, however depending (which you've not quite given us enough information) on what you are using the count for might not be adequate.

I am not sure if you are trying to use this count as a means to short circuit a larger operation or how you are using the count in your application. When you start to highlight 1.4 billion records and you're looking for a window in said set, it sounds like you might be a candidate for partitioned tables.

This allows you assign several smaller tables, typically separated by date, years / months, that act as a single table. When you give the date range on 1.4+ Billion records, SQL can meet performance expectations. This does depend on SQL Edition, but there is also view partitioning as well.

Kimberly Tripp has a blog and some videos out there, and Kendra Little also has some good content on how they are used and how to set them up. This would be a design change. It is a bit complex and not something you would want implement on a whim.

Here is a link to Kimberly's Blog: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/sqlskills-sql101-partitioning/

> Dev banter:

Also, I hear you blaming SQL, are you using entity framework by chance?

Comment: I've updated my question with additional info. Hopefully, this will clarify some of your queries. Also I'm using entity framework but by the looks of it, I will move away from it. Not blaming SQL :). I'm just trying to figure out how to get 'filtered row count' instantly. Regarding the 1.4 billions, thanks for that, but won't be there any time soon, so let's leave that one out for now. I just mentioned it to mention the time it as an example to highlight the time it would take to perform a 'Select count(*)'.